# How to get nth permutation and vice versa given a charset

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, python-itertools

If you have this character set:

```
abc
```

The permutations would be

```
0 = a
1 = b
2 = c
3 = aa
4 = ab
5 = ac
6 = ba
7 = bb
8 = bc
9 = ca
10 = cb
11 = cc
```

And so on and so forth. Is there a way in python to take n, a number representing which permutation it is, and return a corresponding string? And is there a way to do the reverse?

Example:

```
get_word(10, "abc")
#returns cb

get_n("cb", "abc")
#returns 10
```

Comment: it's just math. e.g.: in your example there are 3 one letter strings, 3*3 two letter, 3*3*3 three letter and so on.

Comment: I understand what you are syaing but it is more difficult to program

Comment: These are [permutations with repetition](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html). There are no builtin functions which do the job efficiently, but they can be implemented in a straightforward manner.

Comment: @DJGee: at least give it a try.

Comment: These things are neither permutations nor permutations with repetition. Perhaps if you can find out how to get n's "thing" for the alphabet of 10 characters "0123456789", you might be able to find both an appropriate name and an algorithm for it.

Comment: Technically permutations are just the "sufflings" of given string, so in case of "abc" you have only 6 of them: "abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", and "cba".
What you ask for are [non-empty and finite] strings over given alphabet.

Comment: @n.m. but they are, according to the site I linked. Just the length is not fixed, all of them are put together in the order of increasing length.

Comment: ps the actual answer to both your questions is: YES :) To find the way, you can contemplate n.m.'s comment -- it's a very witty hint! and SO is full of code snippets with what you need, some in python (and even some of these python ones are written by Salvador Dali himself, how cool is that?!). good luck!

Comment: @Gassa "just the length is not fixed" -- precisely because of this they are not ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: The OP is only 15, he may not have studied the relevant mathematics yet.

Comment: @dercz: "it's a very witty hint" - I think you've misunderstood the nature of those permutations... give the task a try and see it yourself.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath -- ``at that moment dercz got enlightened'', thanks!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Are you implying that there's an even easier way to do this than what my code does? If so, I need more clues. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be more efficient ways to do this, but these functions do what you want. Doing the conversions with fixed length strings is easy enough; to handle these variable-length strings we just need to incorporate an offset that accounts for all the strings shorter than the current length. We can easily do that for the forward conversion; for the reverse conversion it's convenient to use the standard formula for the [sum of a geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

```
def gpsum(base, terms):
    return (base ** (terms + 1) - 1) // (base - 1) 

def ntos(n, bstring):
    m = base = len(bstring)
    length = 1
    while m <= n:
        n -= m
        m *= base
        length += 1

    s = []
    for i in range(length):
        n, d = divmod(n, base)
        s.append(bstring[d])
    return ''.join(s)[::-1]

def ston(s, digits):
    base = len(digits)
    n = 0
    for c in s:
        n *= base
        n += digits[c]
    return n + gpsum(base, len(s) - 1) - 1

# Test
bstring = 'abc'
digits = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(bstring)}

maxchars = 4
for i in range(gpsum(len(bstring), maxchars) - 1):
    s = ntos(i, bstring)
    j = ston(s, digits)
    print('{0:>3} {1:>{3}} {2:>3}'.format(i, s, j, maxchars))
```

**output**

```
  0    a   0
  1    b   1
  2    c   2
  3   aa   3
  4   ab   4
  5   ac   5
  6   ba   6
  7   bb   7
  8   bc   8
  9   ca   9
 10   cb  10
 11   cc  11
 12  aaa  12
 13  aab  13
 14  aac  14
 15  aba  15
 16  abb  16
 17  abc  17
 18  aca  18
 19  acb  19
 20  acc  20
 21  baa  21
 22  bab  22
 23  bac  23
 24  bba  24
 25  bbb  25
 26  bbc  26
 27  bca  27
 28  bcb  28
 29  bcc  29
 30  caa  30
 31  cab  31
 32  cac  32
 33  cba  33
 34  cbb  34
 35  cbc  35
 36  cca  36
 37  ccb  37
 38  ccc  38
 39 aaaa  39
 40 aaab  40
 41 aaac  41
 42 aaba  42
 43 aabb  43
 44 aabc  44
 45 aaca  45
 46 aacb  46
 47 aacc  47
 48 abaa  48
 49 abab  49
 50 abac  50
 51 abba  51
 52 abbb  52
 53 abbc  53
 54 abca  54
 55 abcb  55
 56 abcc  56
 57 acaa  57
 58 acab  58
 59 acac  59
 60 acba  60
 61 acbb  61
 62 acbc  62
 63 acca  63
 64 accb  64
 65 accc  65
 66 baaa  66
 67 baab  67
 68 baac  68
 69 baba  69
 70 babb  70
 71 babc  71
 72 baca  72
 73 bacb  73
 74 bacc  74
 75 bbaa  75
 76 bbab  76
 77 bbac  77
 78 bbba  78
 79 bbbb  79
 80 bbbc  80
 81 bbca  81
 82 bbcb  82
 83 bbcc  83
 84 bcaa  84
 85 bcab  85
 86 bcac  86
 87 bcba  87
 88 bcbb  88
 89 bcbc  89
 90 bcca  90
 91 bccb  91
 92 bccc  92
 93 caaa  93
 94 caab  94
 95 caac  95
 96 caba  96
 97 cabb  97
 98 cabc  98
 99 caca  99
100 cacb 100
101 cacc 101
102 cbaa 102
103 cbab 103
104 cbac 104
105 cbba 105
106 cbbb 106
107 cbbc 107
108 cbca 108
109 cbcb 109
110 cbcc 110
111 ccaa 111
112 ccab 112
113 ccac 113
114 ccba 114
115 ccbb 115
116 ccbc 116
117 ccca 117
118 cccb 118
119 cccc 119
```